# Automating a condition to check for an upper threshold

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I have something known as constraint-matrix where each user(muid) can be sent a content(tactic) max N times. So I have  represented it as a dataframe as:

```
tactic   max_times
100      50
101      35
102      23
103      30
...........
.........
```

So each user can be sent tactic named 100 only maximum of 50 times, 101 maximum of 35 times and so on.

Now we have to simulate that each user is send a certain content(tactic) in various iterations.

```
## code to simulate data
import random
muid=range(1,11)
tactic=range(100,110)

##create dataframe for first iteration
temp=DataFrame({'muid':muid,'tactic':tactic})
print temp
    muid    tactic
0   1   100
1   2   101
2   3   102
3   4   103
4   5   104

##reshuffle the sent channel
tactic1=random.sample(range(100,110),10)
##dataframe for second iteration
temp1=DataFrame({'muid':muid,'tactic':tactic1})
print temp1

   muid tactic
0   1   101
1   2   100
2   3   106
3   4   107
4   5   109
5   6   102
6   7   104
7   8   108
8   9   105
9   10  103

###code to calculate how many times user has been sent/exposed to a channel
#groupby for first iteration
groupedby=temp.groupby(['muid','tactic'])['tactic'].agg({'count':'count'})
groupedby.reset_index(inplace=True)

#groupby for second iteration
groupedby1=temp1.groupby(['muid','tactic'])['tactic'].agg({'count':'count'})
groupedby1.reset_index(inplace=True)
appended_output=groupedby.append(groupedby1)
total_counts_at_second_iteration=appended_output.groupby(['muid','tactic'])['tactic'].agg({'total_sent':'count'})
```

so at the end output after second iteration looks like:

```
##top 8 rows
muid    tactic  total_sent
0   1   100 1
1   1   101 1
2   2   101 1
3   2   107 1
4   3   102 1
5   3   104 1
6   4   103 2
7   5   102 1
8   5   104 1
```

The above output corresponds to 2 iterations. Now I want to put the above code in loop(N iterations) and as soon as the constraint is achieved for any sent tactic, that tactic should not be sent anymore and a message should be displayed " limit reached for the tactic". Any help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.random.choice which has an argument p for weights. Then if you keep track of the constraints for each user in a dictionary, you can iterate on each tactic, making sure to update the constraints/weights on each iteration, for each user. Something roughly like the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

muid=range(1,11)
tactic=range(100,110) 

# individual max_constraints for each tactic 
# (Ordering must be consistent with tactic!)
max_times=[50,35,23,30,10,50,5,12,17,22] 

total_times = sum(max_times) # total tactics given out

# keeps track of the number of available tactics (constraints) for each user_id
user_constraint_dict = {user_id:{idn:max_tactic for idn, max_tactic in 
zip(tactic,max_times)} for user_id in muid }

def constraint_to_prob(constraint_dict):

    '''
    convert a dictionary containing weights to probabilities
    for use by np.random.choice
    '''

    total_remaining = float(sum(constraint_dict.values()))
    prob_dict = {tactic:constraint_num/total_remaining for tactic, constraint_num in constraint_dict.iteritems()}

    return prob_dict

tactic_df = pd.DataFrame(index=muid,columns=['tactic_'+str(i) for i in range(total_times)])

for tactic_iter in range(total_times):

    for user_id in tactic_df.index:

        user_weight_dict = constraint_to_prob(user_constraint_dict[user_id])
        user_weights = [user_weight_dict[tac] for tac in tactic]
        chosen_tactic = np.random.choice(tactic,p=user_weights)

        tactic_df.loc[user_id,'tactic_'+str(tactic_iter)] = chosen_tactic

        # update constraints for the given user
        user_constraint_dict[user_id][chosen_tactic]-=1
```